# Configuring TLS for Sentry Relay

Tags: ssl, proxy, sentry, pkcs#12

I have the following config file for [Sentry Relay](https://docs.sentry.io/product/relay/):

```
---
relay:
  mode: static
  upstream: "https://sentry.io/"
  host: 0.0.0.0
  port: 3000
  tls_port: 3001
  tls_identity_path: /etc/cert/keyStore.p12
  tls_identity_password: xxx
```

I am able to ping sentry via port 3000 on the command line:

```
export SENTRY_DSN="http://nfvu4830bvfu3iuujfnvb3809@domain:3000/43275240"
sentry-cli send-event -m "test event"
```

But not port 3001:

```
export SENTRY_DSN="https://nfvu4830bvfu3iuujfnvb3809@domain:3001/43275240"
sentry-cli send-event -m "secure test event"
```

`keyStore.p12` was generated by doing:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout myKey.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
openssl pkcs12 -export -out keyStore.p12 -inkey myKey.pem -in cert.pem
```

And my Sentry Relay server was started using the docker command:

```
sudo docker run --rm -d \
  -v $(pwd)/config/:/etc/relay/ \
  -v $(pwd)/cert/:/etc/cert/ \
  -p 3000:3000 \
  -p 3001:3001 \
  getsentry/relay run --config /etc/relay/
```

In the logs, I can see that both port 3000 and 3001 were opened and ready for connection:

```
 INFO  relay_server::service               > spawning http server
 INFO  relay_server::service               >   listening on: http://0.0.0.0:3000/
 INFO  relay_server::service               >   listening on: https://0.0.0.0:3001/
 INFO  actix_net::server::server           > Starting 2 workers
 INFO  actix_net::server::server           > Starting server on 0.0.0.0:3000
 INFO  actix_net::server::server           > Starting server on 0.0.0.0:3001
```

I cannot figure out what the issue is and why I am unable to send a message through https on port 3001.

Comment: [#1449](https://github.com/getsentry/relay/issues/1499)